# Payment getting declined Cybersource HOP

Tags: java, payment-gateway, sap-commerce-cloud, cybersource

I am able to successfully redirect user to Cybersource payment gateway. But after filling out all the details, I am getting an error "The request data did not pass the required fields check for this application: [bill_address1, bill_city, bill_country, customer_email, customer_lastname]". This is resolved when I change the Secured Acceptance settings from the Cybersource account and allow the user to enter the billing details. But I want to send this details to Cybersource as user is already entering this details in the website. I added the fields in hidden fields and have also mentioned them in signed_field_names and have used them also in generating the signature. Till I am getting this error. Am I passing this fields in wrong way?

Also is there any way to pass custom attributes which I get back in return from Cybersource after payment processing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check field names and order. Those field names look like they are for SCMP. You may need to use the following fields for secure acceptance: bill_to_address_line1, bill_to_address_city, bill_to_address_country, bill_to_email, bill_to_surname.

I would also make sure the data you are sending is valid for those fields. For example, the country field takes only 2 characters.

[Secure Acceptance Documentation](https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API.pdf)

[SCMP Documentation](https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Payer_Authentication_SCMP_API/Payer_Authentication_SCMP_API.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

you should add the above missing data to Signed fields

Comment: An example or code snippet could help here